# Get a conditional summation of 2 vectors

Tags: r

I need help for my homework! Below is the question.

Mean (average) weight (in grams) of apples from a farm are saved in vector w1 for a week and how many apples are collected for the same week is saved in vector n1.

```
w1 <- c(350, 270, 320, 420, 310, 300, 400)
n1 <- c(1220, 780, 563, 1100, 980, 990, 1150)
```

The apple farm believes that minimum apple weight should be 350 grams. Calculate how many apples did not meet the minimum weight criteria in the week? (Assume that all apples in a day have same weight)

I have tried this:

```
sum(w1[which(w1>=350)]*n1)
```

But I get this;

```
[1] 2574900
Warning message:
In w1[which(w1 >= 350)] * n1 :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Answer (score 1):

We need to use the logical vector to subset both vectors instead of 1.  The warning message is due to that reason (one vector is full vector - n1) while the second is subset ('w1')

```
i1 <- w1 < 350
sum(w1[i1] * n1[i1])
```

Or it can be otherwise written as

```
as.numeric(w1[i1] %*% n1[i1])
```

EDIT: As per @RuiBarradas comments

Comment: Doesn't *did not meet the minimum weight criterion* mean `w1 < 350`?